# Derived classes and singleton

Tags: c++, inheritance, oop, singleton

If I have two classes "A" and "B", is it OK to derive B from A and then make B a Singleton?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kind of a subjective question.  You will get some answers saying never to use singletons, and others saying it's fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um, sure. Nobody is going to stop you.

If it's okay to make "some class" a singleton<sup>*</sup>, just imagine B being a new "some class". (It just happens to be derived from A.)

<sup>*</sup>Though, [do you really need a singleton](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/)? (No.)

Comment: Probably No. Just because I have not used my hammer does not mean I may one day find a use for it. But usually my screwdriver works fine.